# Predefinig connections in HAWTIO

Tags: hawtio

Is there a why to have a set of predefined connections so that I can present to a user accessing the console for the first time ?

Thank you, kindly
  Luis Oscar Trigueiros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this moment there is no such way to have and share predefined connections among users. We are aware of the feature request https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2525 and will implement it in the (hopefully near) future.